# I'm learning about object oriented concepts in Apex Code and I keep on getting a "Variable does not exist: name " . What am I doing wrong?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I created a class first:I'm learning about object oriented concepts in Apex Code and I keep on getting a "Variable does not exist: name " . What am I doing wrong?

```
public class Dog 
{
    public String name;
    public integer age;

    public void disp()
    {
        system.debug('Name of my dog '+name);
        system.debug('Age of my dog '+age);
    }

}
```

My Apex Code:

```
Dog d1=new Dog();
d1.name='scooby';
d1.age=12;
d1.disp();

Dog d2=new Dog();
d2.name='tiger';
d2.age=13;
d2.disp();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code compiles and runs just fine.

[image: debug log console output showing 4 statements]

Are you sure you saved changes to the Dog class OK? No compile errors? Perhaps your old version had typo in `name` or maybe that field wasn't marked `public`?

Perhaps you already have another class called `Dog` in this org?

Comment: I actually didn't save the changes. Wow!! Thank you so much.

Comment: happens to the best of us :)